# Simplest way to integrate python gui app with c console app

Tags: python, c, user-interface, integrate

I have a c console app which converts a c file to a html file, the c file location is passed to the program as a command line argument.(the app is for the windows platform)

What I would like to do is have a python gui app to allow the user to select a file and pass the location of the file to the c app for processing.

I already know how to create a basic python gui with tkinter, but I can't figure out or find any usefull info on how I would go about intgrating the two programs.

Maybe its possible to pipe the string to the c app with the pOpen()  method? (but I can't figure out how...)

Note: Im new to python so code examples might be helpful rather then just description, (as Im not familiar with all of the python libraries etc,) although any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

At the very minimum:

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["/path/to/myCprogram", "/path/to/file.c"])
if retcode == 0:
   print "success!"
```

This will run the program with the arguments, and then return its return code.

Note that subprocess.call will block until the program has completed, so if it's not one which runs quickly, your entire Tkinter GUI will stop redrawing until it's completed.

For more advanced use, you may want to use `subprocess.Popen`. This will require you polling until the command has completed, but allows you to do it with less blocking.

If your C program prints the HTML to standard out, you will need to pipe the output like so:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/myCprogram", "/path/to/file.c"], 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err_output = proc.communicate()
# output will now contain the stdout of the program in a string
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I created script to test the subprocess.call method,  hardcoding in filenames etc, and it worked fine, now  I think I need to learn a little more python and Tkinter, so that I can figure out how to put it all together, my OO programing skills are little rusty...

Comment: Ok, I managed to put it all together, which proved a lot simpler then I thought. I Was having some problems which just turned out to be syntactical errors, my dev enviroment is pretty primative at the moment basically consists of notepad++, I will look into a more comprehensive solution when I have time, anyway im rambling...

Now that Iv'e achieved my initial goal, Im interested in how I could  
achieve a higher level of integration, Iv used the .pyw extension so that the dos window only pops up for a split second, but It would be nice if it didn't at all. Is there an easy way to do....

Comment: ...this without going to the trouble of creating a dll and calling the c functions from within the python app.

Comment: There's no easy way, unfortunately. If you ran your python app in a console instead of via pythonw, then at least the apps you run would -probably- not pop up additional consoles, which is less annoying if you have say, a lot of files to process. But even that is not guaranteed. If the popup is undesired, it might be worth investing the time to fix the C app's entry point to not require a console or to turn it into a library.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you could acheive this, but in your case the requirements seems so straightforward all you need is to use `Popen` from the `subprocess` module.

```
 process = subprocess.Popen(['myutil', file_location]...)
 process.wait()
```

If you need to get the results back to the caller, use a PIPE for the stdout and read the resulting data from it when the subprocess has finished.